# How to prove a constant function that neither injective nor surjective in Coq?

Tags: coq

So the definition is giving out as :
`Definition constant {X:Type} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y = c.`
and I need to generate proof for `Theorem const_not_inj : forall c:nat, ~injective (constant c).`

I started proof like this:

```
Theorem const_not_inj : forall c:nat, ~injective (constant c).
unfold injective.
unfold not.
intros.
induction c.
```

then I get stuck having no clue how to continue.
Any thought woule be helpful :)

Comment: That definition of `constant` does not seem right...

Comment: Well, it's OK if you consider **binary relations**  instead of **functions** in Coq's technical meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on Pierre's suggestion, you can just pass, for instance, `0` and `1` to the `H` hypothesis you got after the `intros`, thus getting a contradiction. A short proof in SSReflect would be:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun. 

Definition constant {X:Type} (c:X) := fun x y : X => y = c.

Theorem const_not_inj : forall c:nat, ~injective (constant c).
Proof. by move=> c /(_ 0 1 erefl). Qed.
```

Note that `erefl` is a proof of the equality of identical terms.

Comment: so I figure out how `erefl` works, but is there a way you can do it buy using an absurd hypothesis in the form, A =⇒ F, where A is a false statement,  in order to generate a proof by contradiction?

Comment: This is what you're doing already. Try, for instance, `move=> c /(_ 0 1 erefl) /eqP; rewrite eqE /=.` (but you need to replace `ssreflect ssrfun` by `all_ssreflect` at the beginning of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a function of type `X -> Y`, and `c:Y`. Let Kc be the constant function which returns `c`.

If there exists two different elements `x0`and `x1`in `X`, and if `fun _ => c` were injective, the proposition `Kc x0 = Kc x1`  would imply `x0 = x1`, hence a contradiction.

For the surjective side of your question, you would have to consider the number of  inhabitants of `Y` (2 at least).